# Oracle SQL: single SELECT request for multiple owners

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like your advice on the best method to use.

From a single Oracle server, we have 3 different owners that contain the exact same tables/data structures. Essentially, the owners allow us to separate the data by administrative regions.

Currently, when I want to do a SQL query on the entire data set (regions), I have to do 3 separate queries:

```
select * from owner1.Table1 union all
select * from owner2.Table1 union all
select * from owner3.Table1
```

In this simple example, there are no issues, but if the query is complex, it quickly becomes very difficult to maintain.

So, would there be a more efficient way to make only one global query instead of 3. I guess it's possible to do it via a PL/SQL script, or Dynamic SQL, but I don't know...

Basically, I would like to be able to do (where owners would contain the names of my 3 owners):

```
select * from owners.Table1
```

It is not possible to build views that would contain the data of all 3 owners (there would be too many).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> In this simple example, there are no issues, but if the query is complex, it quickly becomes very difficult to maintain.
>
> So, would there be a more efficient way to make only one global query instead of 3.

Use a sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. a CTE) to combine the queries with the simple `UNION ALL` queries and then perform the complex query on the combined table (rather than trying to perform the queries on the individual tables):

```sql
WITH subquery_name AS (
  select * from owner1.Table1 union all
  select * from owner2.Table1 union all
  select * from owner3.Table1
)
SELECT <your complex query>
FROM   subquery_name;
```

Comment: I would like to avoid making the 3 individual requests. When I mentioned complex queries, it was to illustrate that the individual queries could be very complex (several lines) and having to copy this query 3 times with different owners is probably not the best way to proceed.

Comment: @JGLord You **have** to make 3 queries because you have 3 tables. However, the answer is saying that you can make 3 simple queries and combine them in a sub-query factoring clause (CTE) and then perform one complex query on the generated sub-query.